# Rutear un archivo php en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación en `Laravel`, y me pasaron un script php de otra aplicacion que está programada en php puro, me pidieron migrar ese script a una ruta dentro de mi aplicacion en `Laravel`, sin embargo no estoy muy seguro de como agregar dicho script, ya que generalmente lo he hecho creando una ruta, un template con extensión `.blade.php` y asociarlo a algún `controller`, tengo este código dentro de mi archivo `web.php`

```
Route::get('url', function() {
    return view('path.to.scritp.file');
});
```

donde file es el nombre del achivo php que debo mapear, la verdad no estoy seguro si esto es posible, o si es necesario cambiar la extensión `.php` a `blade.php`

Pero al ir a la url obtuve el siguiente error:

> View [path.to.scritp.file] not found.

**Mi duda en específico es si es posible hacerlo**

Comment: ¿qué hay en dicho archivo que deseas integrar? tal vez sabiendo lo que incluye podamos guiarte mejor.

Comment: La respuesta es **sí, es posible**, pero nos falta información para dar un mejor detalle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependiendo del tipo de archivo

```
Route::get('file/{id}', function(){
    //aqui mi código
});
```

O puedes usar un Controlador para no amontonar todo en tu ruta

```
Route::get('file/{id}', 'SiteController@file');
```

La idea del id de la ruta es que sirva para identificar el archiv, ya sea en una BD o puede ser el nombre del archivo.

Luego en el método tu controlador

```
class SiteController extends Controller{
    public function file($id){
        //traer el archivo desde una url, BD, o similar por ejemplo una imagen
        //ejemplo rustico con PHP
        $file = '../image.jpg'; //url de la imagen
        $type = 'image/jpeg'; //tipo
        header('Content-Type:'.$type); //headers
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
    }
}
```

Puedes ver más con las laravel responses
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses

pero en general esa es la idea.